# Vite production build changes asset urls to wrong location

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vite configuration for my Vue 3 project and when I run a production build, the image path changes.

In my scss file I have the following font-face for FontAwesome:

```
@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('@shared/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('@shared/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0')
      format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('@shared/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0')
      format('woff'),
    url('@shared/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0')
      format('truetype'),
    url('@shared/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular')
      format('svg');
}
```

This works for development, however when I run a production build the font url changes to:

```
/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0.
```

However this is not where my fonts are placed, my fonts are placed in another directory I specified in my build settings. Is there a way to change this behaviour?